# Where to put executable binaries in a Gradle project?

Tags: maven, gradle, convention

Is there a convention where to put binary executable "helper" files like [nssm.exe](http://nssm.cc/) in a Gradle project (or Maven project, if Gradle has no convention)?

At the moment I put this file in `src/scripts` but I feel that an .exe file is not exactly a script ...

Where would you put a helper executable like nssm.exe in a Gradle project?

Answer (score 1):

My only searching of this was in a tutorial for building a C executable. The location given by the tutorial was `./build/exe/` This is documented on the main Gradle Guide site located. [here](https://guides.gradle.org/building-c-executables/)

Maybe this means it's an intended path to create? Hope the link helps somewhat anyway.

Comment: `build/` sounds plausible at first, but it gets deleted when I run `gradle clean`.